# find pattern in string using re module

Tags: python, regex

I need to find the pattern into string if it contain valid. I could not figure to achieve this pattern. I can get value in the below two format and rest should be discard

```
s = "1:5.9,1.5:7,2:10,4:18,8:40"
```

`I need to check that if string  s have <value_1>:<value_2> format`. 
Here I have tried with match and search and found that it need to be done with compile
I want to check that string contain this format

```
<value_1>:<value_2>,<value_3>:<value_4>.... goes on"

 #!/usr/bin/env py
import re
s = "1:5.9,1.5:7,2:10,4:18,8:40"
data  = re.search(r'\d+:\d+',s)
if data:
    print data.group()
```

Comment: Could you please show us what you have tried :)

Comment: Hi, I can not understand 100% of your message. You have a string and you want to look for a pattern in it. re.match or re.search should be usefull in that, can you tell us why you think it didn't work?

Comment: Ok, that gives as a result 1:5, how is it different from what you want?

Comment: So my purpose is, to check the pattern into string if it contain multiple value

Comment: So, if s = "1:5.9,1.5:7,2:10,4:18,8:40" you would like to know that it has the format value1:value2,value3:value4,value5:value6, value7:value8,value9:value10 . Do you want to save the values or just to know if they have that format?

Comment: just want to know the format. if possible than save the value also

Comment: You didn't tell us anything about the values. Are only integers and floats allowed? If so, how many digits? Is "66666666:5.945464,5.6.7.3:54546" valid or not?

Comment: it will only be float or integer with value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand it correctly you need something like this. If the requested pattern is not in the string, you will receive empty list.

**Code**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env py
import re
s = "1:5.9,1.5:7,2:10,4:18,8:40"
data  = re.findall(r'([0-9.]+):([0-9.]+)', s)
if data:
    print data
```

**Output**:

`[('1', '5.9'), ('1.5', '7'), ('2', '10'), ('4', '18'), ('8', '40')]`

**Edit 1:**
Code handle errors and only accept correct values.

```
#!/usr/bin/env py
import re

s = "1:5.9,1.5:7,2:10,4:18,8:40"

raw_data = re.findall(r'(([0-9]+(.)?(?(3)[0-9]+)):([0-9]+(.)?(?(5)[0-9]+)))+', s)
_temp = ','.join([first[0] for first in raw_data])
data = [(p[1], p[3]) for p in raw_data]

if _temp==s:
    print 'Data is correct'
else:
    print 'Data is wrong'
```

Comment: But If I want to report error in the below case s = "1:5.9,1.5:7,2:10,4:18,8" How will I able to report error

Comment: The pattern will match "1.7.5.7:5.9.7:5.6.76:3" as well, which is not the correct format I think.

Comment: @Abhishek Goswami My answer answers to your interrogation

Comment: what is mean of \. in the pattern

Comment: The dot for the floating values: 5.9

Comment: @Abhishek Goswami It matches a simple dot. The dot is special by default and matches any character except newline, so the backslash is used to remove the special meaning.

Comment: I don't see the interest of writing ``(([0-9]+(\.)?(?(3)[0-9]+)):....`` instead of ``[0-9.]+:``

Comment: One can write ``','.join(first[0] for first in raw_data)`` . By the way, I don't see why the name **first** for the elements of raw_data

Comment: [0-9.]+: means everything because the dot. If you use [0-9\.]+ it will accept 1.2 and 4.5.6.7 too. The other complex stuff pass only on ints or floats with one dot. The first variable name is just a name. You can use foo, var, element, e or whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
rdata = re.compile(' *([0-9.]+) *: *([0-9.]+) *')

s = "   1:5.9,  1.5:7,2: 10,4:18,8:40   "


print all(rdata.match(x) for x in s.split(','))


def get(s):
    li = []
    for el in s.split(','):
        m = rdata.match(el)
        if m:
            li.append(m.groups())
        else:
            return False
    return li

print get(s)
```

result

```
True
[('1', '5.9'), ('1.5', '7'), ('2', '10'), ('4', '18'), ('8', '40')]
```

Comment: @Simon Sagi I deleted my comments here. Maybe you should do the same for the one above